# Time driven state transition in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have used one model Student in my application. The student can have two states **valid** and **invalid** which I implemented with state machine. Each student object has one field named **term_end_date**. I want to do the following: if **term_end_date** is equal to **Date.today**, the state transition **:valid => :invalid** should take place.

So I am asking if anyone can give any idea how to implement that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What if you don't store the state, but determine the state on runtime? You could use scopes to fetch Students with the right state:

```
scope :valid, -> { where('term_end_date < ?', Time.now) }
scope :invalid, -> { where('term_end_date >= ?', Time.now) }

def state
  term_end_date < Time.now ? :valid : :invalid
end
```

Call like:

```
Student.valid.where(class: 'Biology')
Student.find(13).state
```

Comment: But how you call that function? I mean there will have to be some kind of cron job that will trigger that function. If I am wrong, please rectify.

Comment: In my answer there is no need for a cron job. You just call `Student.valid` to get all the students that have the valid state at the time you make the call. If you are using a state machine this might not work well. But then, why use a state machine for just two states?

Comment: Actually there are more states, but for the sake of question I did not mention other states. I am sorry, I think I could not clarify my question. Actually I want those students with term_end_date >= Date.today be automatically invalid without any human intervention.

Comment: To clarify: there is no human intervention in my answer, it's just that the state isn't stored but determined at runtime. But as you have other states too, this might not be the best solution. My problem with cronjobs is that not all ten million(!) Students in the DB will be processed at 0:00 exactly.